# Is there some way to navigate along side sections in this Scroll Area?

Tags: reactjs, three.js

Can some one give me any advice, how can i solve problem with navigation in the scollable area from react drei (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-three/drei) tools in front of Canvas 3D background. When i am trying use common navigation between sections with section id="hero" and Banner area. It is working, but scroll area working is scrolling my content with css property translate: translate3d(...). So if i use my  tag with section id. It scrolls to the given id but than i am not able to scroll back to the upper sections.

Here is my code:

[image: 1]

I was expectig regular behavior of  tag navigation